# Android Studio debugger, passed argument has no value

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Just wondering if you have experienced in Android Studio, wherein you created a simple method that accepts n-number of arguments, but the 3rd or 4th so on are not being evaluated by Android Studio? I'm currently stuck in this scenario, the code runs fine without any compile time error. When trying to evaluate the passed argument, Android Studio doesn't recognize the variable name.

Comment: Are you using instant run? If you clean and build it again, does it work?

Comment: What do you mean by _"evaluated by Android Studio"_?

Comment: @EugenMartynov clean and rebuild doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Michael when set a breakpoint on that method, when I try to view the variables in Debug view, it says the variable does not exist and can't evaluate it.